# Norm calculation

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Can some one help me I found it difficult really 
Show that the function is bounded (continuous) 
 and calculate the norm 
$
{f}{(}{x}{)}{=}{x}_{1}{+}{x}_{2}{,}\hspace{0.33em}{x}{=}{(}{x}_{1}{,}{x}_{2}{,...)}\in{l}_{2}
$

Answer (score 1):

$$|f(x)| =|x_1 +x_2  | \leq\sqrt{2}||x|| $$

hence

$$||f|| \leq \sqrt{2}$$

but

$$f(2^{-\frac{1}{2}} ,2^{-\frac{1}{2}} , 0,0, 0,...)=\sqrt{2}$$

thus

$$||f|| \geq \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot can you show me the details